# Interesting differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Given the continuous function $\mathbf{v}:I\to\mathbb{R}^2$, is it posible to solve the following differential equation:

$\mathbf{v}(t)=\mathbf{u}(t)+\dfrac{\mathbf{u'}(t)}{||\mathbf{u'}(t)||}$, where $\mathbf{u}:I\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is in $C^{1}(I)$, and $||\mathbf{u'}(t)||\neq 0, \forall\ t\in I$ ?

Does it have a unique solution, if the initial value is given?

Answer (score 0):

(Partial answer) It cannot be done in general. For example if $v(t) =0$ for all $t\in I$, then

$$u(t) = - \frac{u'(t)}{||u'(t)||} \Rightarrow  ||u(t)|| = 1$$

That is, the trace of $u$ is part of the unit circle. Then

$$0 = \partial_t||u(t)||^2 = 2\langle u(t), u'(t)\rangle$$

This mean that $u(t), u'(t)$ are linearly independent and so $u(t) + \frac{u'(t)}{||u(t)||} = 0$ is impossible.

I guess one can find a necessary and sufficient condition for $v$ to decide whether such a $u$ could be found.

Comment: This is a simplified case of the equation of the bicycle, where $âmathbf{v}$ represents the front wheel, and $\mathbf{u}$ the back one. So there must be just one solution (if the initial conditions are given)